# How to use the Racing Wheel class in the UWP windows.gaming.input namespace

Tags: c++, windows, api, uwp, gamepad

I want to use the [windows.gaming.input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/input-for-games) to connect my Thrustmaster T300 with Force-Feedback. Some background information: I have to read all data (steering angle, buttons, ...) from the steering wheel and simply display them in a command prompt. If this works, I would like to add the functionality to send the wheel a desired moment (force feedback) and duration. I'm not really deep into C++ (have little experience with it). I read some articles about how to read the wheel and chose the UWP (Universal Windows Program) with its windows.gaming.input API over DirctInput or InputX.

I browsed through the documentation page of [windows.gaming.input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/input-for-games) and found that there is a racing bike class in the namespace [windows.gaming.input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/input-for-games) --> [racing wheel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/racing-wheel-and-force-feedback).

But now I have the problem that I really can't get anything working with the documentation provided by Microsoft. It's most likely due to my lack of c++-skills, to be frankly I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Post what attempts you have made, and we'll try and help with them.

Comment: Also clarify which projection you are using. (Current recommendation is C++/WinRT.) According to the page you linked, "Detecting and tracking racing wheels works in exactly the same way as it does for gamepads, except with the RacingWheel class instead of the Gamepad class." So use `RacingWheel.RacingWheels` property to find all the racing wheels.

Comment: Hello, I saw the [same question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/27736/how-to-use-the-racing-wheel-class-in-the-uwp-windo.html) in Q&A and my colleague will track your question there.